# react-native: InputText activity firing TouchableHighlight onPress() events

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, expo

I have the following react-native code where I am trying to build a custom form to gather user input. The form renders correctly with 3 input boxes and a Save button.

In the code below, the issue is that as soon as I start typing on the first `TextInput` field, the `this.saveFormData()` which is called only inside the `TouchableHighlight` button gets fired!

Why are the `TextInput` events conflicting with the `TouchableHighlight` ones? How do I fix the issue?

```
class NewScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { songTitle: null, chord: null, strumPattern: null };
  }

  saveFormData = () => {
    console.log(this.state.songTitle);
    () => navigate("Home");
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
          <View style={styles.row_cell_chord_songTitle}>
            <Text style={styles.new_input_label}> Song Title </Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.new_input_field}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ songTitle: text })}
              value={this.state.songTitle}
            />
            <Text style={styles.new_input_label}> Chords </Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.new_input_field}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ chord: text })}
              value={this.state.chord}
            />

            <Text style={styles.new_input_label}> Strumming Pattern </Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.new_input_field}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ strumPattern: text })}
              value={this.state.strumPattern}
            />
          </View>


            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.saveButton}
              onPress={this.saveFormData()} // <-- typing on above Inputbox fires this function.
            >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                <FontAwesome>{Icons.heart}</FontAwesome> Save
              </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight> */
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a function to onPress, currently you're invoking the function and passing whatever it returns. You just need to change it to:

```
onPress={this.saveFormData}
```